# Khan SmileyFace - Infinite Loop Trouble

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm working on the SmileyFace project in Khan Academy.  It's harder than I've been able to do so far.

Why is the text command outputting an infinite loop?  The output should be 'Hello.' but is printing:

```
"function(speak){
__env__KAInfiniteLoopCount++;
if (__env__KAInfiniteLoopCount++<"
```

...and more lines after this.

Thank you.  Here is my code:

```
var SmileyFace = function(centerX,centerY){
    this.centerX = centerX; 
    this.centerY = centerY;
};

SmileyFace.prototype.draw = function() {
    fill(255, 234, 0);
    ellipse(this.centerX, this.centerY, 150, 150);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse(this.centerX-30, this.centerY-30, 20, 20); 
    ellipse(this.centerX+30, this.centerY-30, 20, 20); 
    noFill(); 
    strokeWeight(3);
    arc(this.centerX, this.centerY+10, 64, 40,0,180);  
};

SmileyFace.prototype.speak = function(speak){
    text(this.speak,this.centerX,this.centerY+40);
}; 

var face = new SmileyFace(200,300);
    face.draw();
    face.speak("Hello.");
```

Comment: Because in `speak` you are passing `this.speak` to `text`

Comment: What line is it complaining about, in which file? There's a lot of code missing here, so it's not possible at the moment to identify where the problem is. Sneaking suspicion that you should pass `speak` instead of `this.speak` in that `text` call though.

Comment: Also do you have a link to the original assignment? Can you include that in the question?

Comment: The output you see is the source of a function. KanAcademy is injecting additional code into your function to catch cases like infinite loops.

Comment: Yes, the link you used was the assignment.  For anyone else looking at it:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/challenge-smileyface-step-4/5935891585957888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right here:

```
SmileyFace.prototype.speak = function(speak){
    text(this.speak,this.centerX,this.centerY+40);
};
```

Instead of passing the *variable* `speak` to the function `text` you are passing the *function* `speak`. So instead of `this.speak`, do just `speak`.

This is why it's a good idea not to have functions and variables with the same name.

If you look at [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/challenge-smileyface-step-4/5935891585957888) which I assume is where you got the assignment from, you'll notice the difference in how they did it:

```
SmileyFace.prototype.speak = function(hey) {
    fill(255, 0, 174);
    text(hey,this.centerX-4, this.centerY+100);
};
```

They pass the argument `hey` (which to avoid confusion doesn't have the same name as the function! - but is kind of a dumb name...) to the `text` function. If you change theirs to `this.speak` you see exactly the behavior you described.

Comment: Matt Burland is correct;
Because in the function call you've supplied speak as a function-parameter, it's not available in the this.-context, but only without this. appended.

Comment: Yeah, I would call that variable text or textToSpeak, something like that as a noun. It's more meaningful and avoids the verb use of the speak function itself.

Comment: Thank you guys so much.  My dad and I are amazed at the quality of answers people share.